# How to spoof GPU vendor id and device id in VMWare?

Tags: virtual-machine, graphics-card, vmware, spoofing

I am trying to run a particular game in a VMWare machine (which is able to run many other games), but this game has an arbitrary check which prevents launching if the GPU you're using is unrecognized. It gives this error:

> Unsupported video card detected! Continuing to run might lead to
> unexpected results or crashes. Please check the manual for further
> information on hardware requirements.
>
> "VMware SVGA 3D" [vendor id = 0x15ad, device id = 0x0405]

After some research I figured out I could edit/replace some of the values in the registry so I began replacing the name "VMware SVGA 3D" with my real graphics card name "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER" everywhere in the registry. In one particular place of the registry the value wouldn't "stick" and kept getting rewritten on startup. I fiddled with the permissions, taking away full control permission from the SYSTEM, but it didn't work until I set literally every permission including my own to "deny". Then, that registry entry disappeared from my view because I denied my own permission to edit, but when I restarted, the error message changed to:

> Unsupported video card detected! Continuing to run might lead to
> unexpected results or crashes. Please check the manual for further
> information on hardware requirements.
>
> "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER" [vendor id = 0x15ad, device id =
> 0x0405]

Therefore I successfully spoofed the name but what I really need to spoof are vendor id and device id. I found a guide on https://grimore.org/windows/spoof_hardware_identifiers but ran into the same issue where the registry entry kept getting overwritten on restart even if I fiddled with permissions. I did the same thing as before (changing all the permissions to "deny") but it still didn't seem to fix the issue. The error message remains the same as above (GPU name changed successfully, vendor id and device id unchanged)

Common non-answers I read on other threads:

- "The performance won't be good" -- I don't care about the
  performance; I just want to run it on this VM.
- "It won't work, game won't run etc" -- Since they are only blocking it because the device/vendor id are unrecognized, I believe this is only a case of the virtual GPU being unknown, not incapable.

Comment: There's no [official](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Change-VGA-graphics-adapter-vendor-id/td-p/1753713) way to do that in Workstation, but *somewhere* they must be storing this information. I did try to hex edit the LegacyBiosDxe and VmwSvgaDxe drivers inside of EFI64.ROM (search for `AD150504` with UEFITool) but to no avail. [Maybe](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Can-the-quot-VMware-quot-bios-splash-screen-be-changed/td-p/526706) if I had switched to an older virtualHW version or to bios firmware I'd have had a better time but I didn't try.